# Can I use a variable to name other variables?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on some code that requires lots of data to be stored and I want to write a new data type for these to be placed into.

```
     Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
         Dim myFile As String, text As String

         myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename() 
         Open myFile For Input As #1

         Do Until EOF(1)
             Line Input #1, text
             'Check to see if line contains name
             If InStr(text, "name=") <> 0 Then
                 'Trim down to just name
                 text = Replace(text, "name=", "")
                 text = Trim(text)
                 'Set the current value of text as name of new scalarIn
                 Dim text As scalarIn
             End If 
        Loop

    End Sub
```

I don't think this works but its more to help understand the idea. What I want to happen is to read in a name from a file and set it as the name of a new instance of my custom data type.

```
Public Type scalarIn
    UnitOfMeasure As String
    Value As Variant
    Source As String 
End Type
```

Comment: Create an array of your *scalarIn* class and **ReDim Preserve** the array as it grows. It is difficult to offer anything beyond that without knowing more about the custom *scalarIn* class. Alternately, use a *Scripting.Dictionary* object with the text as the *key*.

Comment: I have trouble connecting your question to your code to your title.  If you want to create your own type, use [a class module in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx).  If `scalarIn` exists, then @Jeeped is right about creating an array to store them.  You can pass properties to your class if that's what you mean by naming them, but why are we naming them?  I guess... what's your question?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been programming all too long. `scalarIn` is just a type I created with a few variables inside that get initiated.                           `Public Type scalarIn

UnitOfMeasure As String
Value As Variant
Source As String

End Type`

Comment: A sample of the line(s) from the input text file along with a description of what you want to do with the information once you have it would help.

Comment: That `Dim text As scalarIn` inside the loop is evil. It doesn't do what you think it does.